# Lookup Column for Doc Library

Tags: lookup-column

I have a library where users upload trainings for different teams. Each team has a different set of training so as of now, the training dropdown for the Training choice field is so much to scroll through. What I would like to do is have the Team field first, and depending on the value selected in the team field, only show the trainings for that team in the Training field.

I know that this can be accomplished with lookup columns, but I have been unsuccessful in my endeavors.

**EDIT** : So I know that this works with singular values, but what about multiple values like a choice column? Would I just have to make multiple list items for each team in the lookup list?

Comment: Do a search for "SharePoint cascading drop-downs", that should help you find what you need.

Comment: @DylanCristy is it possible without SP Services

Comment: Yes, but it would involve you writing all the JavaScript code to do what SPServices does for you: 1) listen for a change event on the Team dropdown; 2) take that value and query the list where all the lookup connections are set; 3) take those results and populate the Training dropdown.  There is no out-of-the-box way to get this feature in SharePoint, which is why using SPServices is such a popular solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a managed metadata column, which filters for terms in a term set (training choices) as you begin typing in the input box. This will save your users having to scroll through a long list and if the values need to be updated, this can be done very easily from the term store.